# Retrieving data from Firebase of contact List only

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android app where I want to retrieve posts of the users, whose contact numbers are saved in the mobile in the decreasing order of `timestamp`.

For now I am retrieving all the list of users. And displays posts of the user if contact number exists in mobile. As I want to sort in decreasing order of timestamp, I have to retrieve the posts of all the contacts first and than sort them.

```
Users: { 
            7828272892 : {
                 name: xyz, 
                 gender: male,
                 phoneNo: 7828272892
                 PostsForThisUser: {
                     SomeKey1: {
                         content: "This is post 1", timestamp: "123"} 
                     SomeKey2: {
                         content: "This is post 2", timestamp: "124"}   

                }},

            7924272894 : {
                name: abc,
                gender: male,
                phoneNo: 7924272894
                PostsForThisUser: {
                         SomeKey3: {
                             content: "This is post 1", timestamp: "234"} }},
            }
```

A better solution I can think of is, Making separate table for posts and keep track through key of the posts. But, here too I have to get all the posts first and sort them by timestamp. Is there any better solution?

Which is better?

1. To retrieve all Users and then check in the contact list.
2. To open listener for every contact number in the mobile.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Not yet. I am using what I described in the question for now.

Comment: Do you think that will help you if I'll write you an answer now, regarding also a change in your database structure?

Comment: Surely it will. I am open to any structural changes that can help.

Comment: Good, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, even if your schema might help you achieve what you want, I can say that it's not a very feasible one because you are adding under each user object, all its posts. This means that everytime your are trying to get some details of a particular user (let's say the `name`), you are downloading the entire user object, including all his post, which I can say is a waste of bandwidh an resources. Try to think what can happen if you'll need to display the list of all user names in your database. So beside the user name, you'll download all the posts of all users. That's a bad practice.

Remember, that there is no perfect solution for structuring a Firebase database. The best solution, is the solution that fits your needs and makes your job easier. Having in mind that everything is for the view, in my opinion you can have a schema in which you should create a new top level collection named `posts` and under each user phone number to add its personal posts. The schema should look like this:

```
 Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
    |    |
    |    --- userPhoneNo
    |          |
    |          --- name: "xyz,"
    |          |
    |          --- gender: "male"
    |          |
    |          --- phoneNo: "7828272892"
    |
    --- posts
         |
         userPhoneNo
            |
            --- postIdOne
            |     |
            |     --- content: "This is post 1"
            |     |
            |     --- timestamp: 123
            |
            --- postIdTwo
                  |
                  --- content: "This is post 2"
                  |
                  --- timestamp: 124
```

So in order to get all the posts of a particular user, there is no need to download anything else. To get all the posts of a particular user ordered using a model class, please use the following code:

```
String phoneNo = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("posts").child(phoneNo).orderByChild("timestamp");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            PostClass postClass = ds.getValue(PostClass.class);
            Log.d("TAG", postClass.getContent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Or even simpler if you want, using the String class:

```
String phoneNo = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("posts").child(phoneNo).orderByChild("timestamp");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String content = ds.child("content").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", content);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In both situations, the output in your logcat will be:

```
This is post 1
This is post 2
```

Or if you are using a reverse order:

```
This is post 2
This is post 1
```

**Edit:** According to the comments from the chat, the OP asked for a solution regarding a issue that sounds like this:

"Let me restate my problem. In my system I have lets say 10,000 users. But a user will be only able to see the posts of users whose contact number he had. It's like WhatsApp story feature."

The response: In this case, you should create a `map` under each user, where you'll need to store the user contact numbers the user has. But in this case, you should query your database twice. First to get the contact numbers a user he have and second, based on those numbers to actually get the posts of those users.

Comment: Actually I have to get posts of all the users from my contact list. Let's say I have 200 contacts. So, I need to retrieve all the posts of all the users before sorting by timestamp ? Do I need to open listeners for every contact to download data ?

Comment: No, you don't need to attach a listener for every contact to download. If you want to a list of all post of all user, you shoud use denormalization (duplication data) which is quite common practice in Firebase. So you need to create a new collection named `allPosts`. This collection should hold all the posts of all users. In this case you'll need to attach a single listener that will download only the post and **not** the posts and user details as in your database structure, right?

Comment: For more details I also recommend you to see [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding. It is for Firebase real-time database but sae principle aplies to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Just a quick question. So, If I have 10,000 users on my system. `allposts` will have the posts of all the users. Then, if I want to show a user posts of the users from his mobile contact list only. I have to download whole `allposts` and take out the posts of the contact list and display them ?

Comment: **No**, in that case you should get user posts from `userPhoneNo` node (`root -> posts -> userPhoneNo`) as I mentioned in my answer. To be more clear, a single post of a user will exist in 2 places, that's why I said about denormalization. The first place will be under `root -> posts -> userPhoneNo` from where you should load only the posts of a single user and the second place will be in `root -> allPosts` from where you can get the posts of all users.

Comment: One more thing to note, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: So, if I want posts of all the 200 contacts (may be only 5-10 will have account on the system but I need to check all) on an activity. I have to use 200 `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` like `root -> posts -> user1FromMobileContacts` and if `snapshot.exists()` display posts ?

Comment: No, if you want all the post of all your 200 contacts, then you should attach a single listener on the `allPosts` node and get in a single step all posts, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177396/discussion-between-tarun14110-and-alex-mamo).